# pyodbc: Working with postgreSQL parameters that were added after data collection has started

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have a snippet of code that is pushing an error and I am not sure why.

```
currentPeak = cursor.execute("SELECT MAX(value) FROM table WHERE (year = 2022 AND month = 3 AND (bypass != 2 OR bypass == None));").fetchval()
return currentPeak
```

The problem is in the addition of the bypass. The bypass goes from 1 to 3, but I want to filter out the 2s. The reason for the `None` is that I added these columns later on after data had already been collected for awhile, so the beginning row values return `None`. Incorporating the bypass in this manner, I get the following error.

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42703', '[42703] ERROR: column "none" does not exist;\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

How can I get it to filter out 2's while accepting 'None'?

Comment: seems like you're writing python expressions and not sql expressions...? `bypass <> 2 or bypass is not null`

Answer (score 1):

Your query starts with SQL but then you seem to mix in some python.

```sql
SELECT MAX(value)
FROM table
WHERE (
    year = 2022
    AND month = 3
    AND (bypass <> 2 OR bypass IS NULL)
);
```

Note, `!=` also means not equal but is not ISO conformant.

Comment: That did the trick! Very much appreciated to the both of you, Ijmc and thebjorn.